# DC offset to an ADC reduces dynamic range which reduces accuracy. How to quantify accuracy due to loss of dynamic range?

Tags: adc, dsp, accuracy, resolution

It’s understood that the dynamic range of the ADC should match the max amplitude of the signal to achieve maximum accuracy. If it doesn’t, you lose digital codes which reduces accuracy.
How can one quantify this loss of accuracy?

Comment: I think you mean *precision* and not *accuracy*.

Comment: You can characterise it by saying 'I was going to get (for instance) 1024 possible different codes, now I only get 600'. You can express that ratio in dB, or in bits, or just with those numbers. I'm not sure you're using 'dynamic range' in quite the way that signal processing people use it, and as periblepsis has pointed out, not using 'accuracy' 'correctly' either. But hey, I need to look up what accuracy and precision are supposed to mean before I engage with signal processing pedants.

Comment: Dynamic range is *usually* specified as dBFS (dB referred to Full Scale) - i.e.  using all available input range. When you use a smaller range of input then the relevant dynamic range is dBc (dB referred to carrier). The 'carrier' level is the actual range you are using. See figure 2-54 in https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/Data-Conversion-Handbook/Chapter2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic range for an ADC is usually specified as dBFS (dB referred to full scale). The 0dB point here is using the entire available input range.

When using a smaller range, then we use dBc (dB referred to carrier).

Note that dynamic range is measured from the highest unwanted spur in the output spectrum from DC to the Nyquist bandwidth (f0 / 2).

Let's take a hypothetical ADC with dynamic range of 100dBFS. If we can only use 0.1 of the input range (-20dB) then you will have a dynamic range of 80dBc.

So take the dB ratio *20 log(10) [V(in) / V(range)]* and subtract from dBFS. Note that you can use RMS values for the voltages.